# JS - Отобразить дату без временной зоны в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть вот такой код:

```
<CommonInfoBlockItem title="Поле" value={fullInfo.expirationDate}/>
```

И он отображается вот так: `Поле 2020-05-31T00:00:00.000Z`.

Как убрать временную зону из отображения и получить:

```
Поле 2020-05-31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто обрезать строковое представление даты методом `split`.

```
const [info, _] = fullInfo.expirationDate.split('T')
```

А вообще для работы с датами удобнее использовать [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/)